# How to print float number using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code suppose to print float value, but instead of that, the value printed like this "0", however the expected value supposes to be "0.0"

```
 $("#lvl_upStream").html(parseFloat(data.lvl_upStream) + " m");
```

in addition, the following code has been used but still print the same result.

```
$("#lvl_upStream").html(getFloat(data.lvl_upStream) + " m");
```

Value to be printed:

```
"lvl_upStream":0.0
```

Comment: current output ??????????????

Comment: as you can see in my question, is single zero "0"

Comment: Please do a quick google search before asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)** to setnumber of digits appear after the decimal point

```
$("#lvl_upStream").html(parseFloat(data.lvl_upStream).toFixed(1) + " m");
```

```js
var data = '0';
document.write(parseFloat(data).toFixed(1) + " m");
```

Comment: yeah, it works, gonna mark it as answer :)

Comment: @Algiri : glad to help :)